# Firebase Emulator Cloud Functions getFiles() retrieve no file

Tags: firebase, function, storage, hosting, firebase-tools

From cloud functions I want to list all the files in the storage bucket.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const gcs = new Storage();

exports.listFiles = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const [files] = await gcs.bucket("default-bucket").getFiles();
  let filesArray = [];
  files.forEach((file) => {
    filesArray.push(file.name);
  });
  res.status(200).send({ filesArrayName: filesArray });
});
```

This is working fine when the functions is run remotely, but using the Firebase Emulator, I can list the buckets, upload a file, but the query getFiles() will always show an empty array.

Is it an issue with credentials ? My GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable is set on my local machine, and I added the serviceAccount JSON file when doing admin.initializeApp(), but the result still the same. It's really curious that I can list the buckets but not the file..

Here is my storage rules on local

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

On my local machine :
[image: query from my local machine]

[image: emulator storage screenshot]

On the cloud :

[image: query functions from the cloud]

[image: storage on cloud]

Comment: @YayoArellano Unfortunately no.

Comment: I found it's a limitation in the Firebase Emulator. Here is the issue on github https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3778

Comment: Has been fixed on https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v10.3.0